# express: Cannot find module 'html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Проблема такая, вот это вот:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const content  = '<div>555</div>';

    res.render('index', (req, res) => {
        res.send(content);
    });
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Пытался добавить engine вручную

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

...получаю:

> Error: Cannot find module 'html'

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, разобрался сам. Оказывается метод "render" нужен для сторонних обработчиков шаблонов. Мне подойдёт метод "send".